# Run bash in restricted mode when called by R "?" help command

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, r, rstudio

I often use the terminal built in to Rstudio to run interactive R commands and scripts remotely on a server. Occasionally I end up executing in terminal when R is not running in terminal. This can happen for a number of reasons, but one is that after having run the R command "?library" in terminal, the terminal is actually in the bash shell.

The problem that arises is that R commands often have ">" since this is the command prompt in R, or the command may be "Var1 > Var2". This will inadvertently create files in the remote working directory via the linux redirection operator. I am happy to set noclobber to avoid catastrophic overwrites, but I also want to avoid creating new files.

One way to address this is to disable the ">" for the entire ssh session. I asked about this elsewhere, and understand it is not possible without disabling most of bash by running in restricted mode.

A better solution would be to automatically run bash in restricted mode but only when it is exposed by calling "?" in the remote terminal R session.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Comment: I think the two partial solutions deserve two distinct questions.

Comment: I removed the question about how to change the color of the R help page in terminal.

Comment: I can't reproduce. In the terminal in R Studio, I started `R`, ran `?library`, exited the pager showing the help, and I was still in R.

Comment: The point is that if you send code to terminal (strike the ctrl opt enter with highlighted source code in the editor) while terminal is reading the help file, it is interpreted as bash commands...